# Capture data from string not containing duplicate group of characters and strings

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to verify and extract data coming from API. I need to extract text between [] brackets which can be anywhere in the data. e.g.

```
This is [extract] message
This is message [extract] 
[extract] this message
```

Regular expression, I was using for this as below was working fine

```
^[^\]\[]*?\[(?<description>[^\]\[]+)\][^\]\[]*?$
```

Now the data from API can be HTML encoded and have %5B instead of [ and %5D instead of ].

I updated regular expression to below:

```
^[^\]\[%5B%5D]*?(\[|%5B)(?<description>[^\]\[%5B%5D]+)(\]|%5D)[^\]\[%5B%5D]*?$/i
```

But it is not treating %5B and %5D as single atom. And therefore not able to extract text from following valid data:

```
This is [extract] message %
This is message 5 [extract] 
[extract d] this message
```

And able to extract text from following invalid data:

```
[extract %5D this message 
%5B extract ] this message
```

How can I treat %5B and %5D as atoms and correct above regex?

Comment: I'd decode the string before running the regex against it. Regex works best on plain text.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to decode the string, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your first regex should be written as

```
^[^][]*\[(?<description>[^][]+)][^][]*$
```

Note there is no point escaping `[` inside a character class and there is no need escaping `]` inside the character class if it is the first char there and the `]` outside the character class. Also, no need using lazy quantifiers `*?`, you can use `*` equally well.

Now, you should decode the string to the plain text and then run the above regex. If you do not want to do that, you will have to use a complex regex based on a tempered greedy token like

```
^(?:(?!%5[DB])[^][])*(?:%5B|\[)(?<description>(?:(?!%5[DB])[^][])+)(?:]|%5D)(?:(?!%5[DB])[^][])*$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3a(%3f!%255%5bDB%5d)%5b%5e%5d%5b%5cn%5d)*(%3f%3a%255B%7c%5c%5b)(%3f%3cdescription%3e(%3f%3a(%3f!%255%5bDB%5d)%5b%5e%5d%5b%5cn%5d)%2b)(%3f%3a%5d%7c%255D)(%3f%3a(%3f!%255%5bDB%5d)%5b%5e%5d%5b%5cn%5d)*%5cr%3f%24&i=This+is+%5bextract%5d+message%0d%0aThis+is+message+%5bextract%5d+%0d%0a%5bextract%5d+this+message%0d%0aThis+is+%255Bextract%255D+message%0d%0aThis+is+message+%255Bextract%255D%0d%0a%255Bextract%255D+this+message&o=m) (additional patterns are added since it is a multiline demo).

**Regex explanation**:

- `^` - string start
- `(?:(?!%5[DB])[^][])*` - a tempered greedy token matching any 0+ symbols other than `]` and `[` (see `[^][]`) that is not the starting char for a `%5B` or `%5D` char sequence
- `(?:%5B|\[)` - the leading delimiter, a `%5B` or `[`
- `(?<description>(?:(?!%5[DB])[^][])+)` - The "description" group matching 1+ symbols other than `]` and `[` that is not the starting char for a `%5B` or `%5D` char sequence (**NOTE**: you might want to replace with with `(?<description>(?s:.+?))` subpattern to check if that works for you better).
- `(?:]|%5D)` - trailing delimiter, `]` or `%5D`
- `(?:(?!%5[DB])[^][])*` - see above (2nd line)
- `$` - end of string.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for correcting the regex and explanation, quite useful!!